# Can I create a directive for translations instead of a pipe?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-pipe

I am creating a translations module, the translations are stored locally using PouchDB.  And we have 2 fallbacks instead of just one which makes the most popular translation plugin incompatible.

The problem is that having the pipe set to `pure: false` causes performance issues but I cant find any way to force the pipe to work when needed rather than running onchange.

So is there a way to do it via a directive instead?

Comment: You can use pure `pipe` itself for the same. What is the issue you are facing? the data is not available before the pipe translates the `string`?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it.

Comment: how about async pipe then?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use of `APP_INITIALIZER` provided by angular,
The APP_INITIALIZER injection token is a way for you to take part in the Angular app initialization process to do your own work.

Create `AppConfigService` which loads the translation stuffs from the DB.

```
@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {

    constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {
    }

    public load() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          // TranslateService.getLocaleProperties => You can make use to load transaltion stuffs. This returns Observable.
            this.translateService.getLocaleProperties().subscribe(
                (response) => {
                    resolve(true);
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.error("The localization resources are not loaded.");
                    resolve(true);
                });
        });
    }
}
```

**In `app.module.ts`, you do these changes,**

Create `configLoad` factory, which has function that calls the load method of `AppConfigService`.

`export function configLoad(config: AppConfigService) {
  return () => config.load();
}`

in `providers: []` array provide `APP_INITIALIZER`

`{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: configLoad, deps: [AppConfigService], multi: true },`